# Making a certain id disapear once I scroll within a specific section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to make a specific id (#logo) disapear once I scroll in specific section id ("#performance-graphs"), the id that is hidden must show itself again once I have scrolled out that section.

Please see my code below, currently id does not work but the idea is there, not sure what I am doing wrong. basically I trying to make my main header smaller by removing the logo when it gets to the chart section.

JQUERY CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#performance-charts').scroll(function() {
var scroll = $('#performance-charts').scrollTop();
if (scroll > 10) {
$('#logo').css("display", "hidden").fadeOut(250);
}
else { 
$('#logo').css("display", "block").fadeIn(250);
}
});
});
</script>
```

HTML SNIPPET BODY

```
<section id="performance-graphs">
<a id="performance-graphs"></a>
<div class="double-space"></div>    
    <div class="centered-wrapper">
        <h1 class="section-title">charting performance</h1>

...............................................................

</div>
</section>
```

HTML SNIPPET HEADER

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"><header id="fixed" class="solid-header">
    <div class="centered-wrapper">
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service"><div itemprop="ServiceType" content="Asset and Fund Management"></div></div>
    <div id="logo"><a href="../index.html"><img src="../images/value_images/VPM_global3a.png" alt="White Fleet Globel Select Opportunities"></a>
      <p><a href="http://www.valueportfolio.co.za" target="_blank" class="link">LU0721514452:USD - Managed by Value Portfolio Managers (Pty) Ltd</a></p></div>
    <a href="../index-backup.html" title="Value Portfolio Home Page"></a><br>
    <a class="nav-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i><span>Menu</span></a>BaB
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey. Can you please make a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/) with you code and the possibility to see the problem?

Comment: Hi Thank you for responding,  Unfortuntely not allowed to put website live until it is ready, I have created a Jfiddle using the some basic updated code. http://jsfiddle.net/Jason1975/r81r61q4/ basically once I scroll into the section ( #performance-graphs ) i need the logo int he to disapear and when I scroll out of that section I need the logo to show again.

Comment: Thanks for the example code. Made an answer with a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here you go. I used your fiddle and updatet it [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/r81r61q4/2/)

Basically you have bad code there, because an id should be unique! (i just added another charakter to one of the duplicated IDs.

I just updated your JS Code like this:

```
 if ($(document).scrollTop() > $('section#performance-graphss').offset().top) {
```

Because you need the `offset().top` of your graph container and compare it to the scroll position of the qhole document.

---

EDIT:

Does this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r81r61q4/3/) help?

I just added another check for hiding the element:

```
 $('section#performance-graphss').offset().top + $('section#performance-graphss').height() > $(document).scrollTop()
```

So when you scroll past the container the logo gets `display: blick;` again.

Watch out for the CSS i added: The containers need a height.

```
#performance-graphss {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: That works well, there is a section afterwards how would I malipulate the code so that once I scroll pass the graph section the logo comes back.